# SKMaps annotation jumping while Navigation on Real Mode

Tags: android, ios, skmaps

When i start navigation in my project my annotation jumped from one latitude & longitude to another instead of smoothly moving.Due to this issue the road loaded with a small jerk.How can i make my navigation smooth like google and waze app.
I am using GpsTracker class for gps updates on 1 sec of time and 10 meters of distance.Kindly suggest me some way for smooth navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android you should be using the SKPositionPositionProvider instead. To implement the SKPositionPositionProvider you should do:

```
    SKCurrentPositionProvider positionProvider = new SKCurrentPositionProvider(activity);
    positionProvider.setCurrentPositionListener(new SKCurrentPositionListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCurrentPositionUpdate(SKPosition currentPosition) {
            SKPositionerManager.getInstance().reportNewGPSPosition(currentPosition);

        }

    });
    positionProvider.requestLocationUpdates(true, true, false);
```

Comment: Can you help me out for navigation arrow issue.